# Little $o$ and derivative

Tags: derivatives, asymptotics

I know that when $f(x)$ is differentiable,

$$f(x+c)=f(x)+f'(x)c+o(c).$$

I'm trying to express the following $$(h(a+c)-h(a))+(g(b-c)-g(b))$$ with little $o$, my attempt is as follows

$$h'(a)c+o(c)-g'(b)c+o(c)=c(h'(a)-g'(b)+2o(1)).$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and simply we can write for $c\to 0$

$$h'(a)c+o(c)-g'(b)c+o(c)=c(h'(a)-g'(b)+\color{red}{o(1)})$$

since $$2\cdot o(1)=o(1)$$

Comment: Great! As $c \rightarrow 0$ will $o(1) \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: @pafnuti Yes of course, simply remember the by definition $o(1)=1\cdot \omega(c)$ with $\omega(c)\to 0$ for $c\to 0$,